# Showing that $(\phi^2(\vec x),\phi(\vec x),\vec x)$ is a free family, $\phi^2(\vec x)\neq \vec 0, \phi^3(\vec x)= \vec 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, free-groups

> Let be $A\in M_4(\mathbb C)$ such that with $O_4$ representing the null matrix of rank $4$,
>
> $$A^2\neq O_4 \mbox{ and } A^3=O_4$$
>
> Let be $\phi$ the endomorphism of $\mathbb C^4$ canonically associated to $A$.

1. **How to justify the existence of $\vec x\in\mathbb C^4$ such that $\phi(\vec x)\neq\vec 0$**
2. **How to show that $(\phi^2(\vec x),\phi(\vec x),\vec x)$ is a free family?**

I had no idea, I'm very bad to be creative with these kind of questions.

1. As far as $A^2\neq O$ then $A\neq O$ therefore $\phi\vec x\neq \vec0
2. this one is not easy for me: $\phi^2(\vec x)$ is free in the basis $(\phi^2(\vec x),\phi(\vec x),\vec x)$ iif $¬\exists\lambda,\mu, \phi^2(\vec x)=\lambda\phi(x)+\mu\vec x$ I supposed that it existed to find a contradiction but didn't found it.

   $$Ax^2-\lambda A\vec x -\mu \vec x=\vec 0$$

$$\Leftrightarrow (A^2-\lambda A-\mu I)\vec x=\vec0$$

....

Comment: I do not understand the second point. Surely the fact that $\phi(\vec x)\neq\vec 0$ does not imply that $(\phi^2(\vec x),\phi(\vec x),\vec x)$ is free? It could even happen that $\phi^2(\vec x)=\vec0.$

Comment: @Marine1 please, can you enlighten us about the exact redaction of the assignment. I believe the second one is "Show that there exists an $\vec x$ such that $(\phi^2 (\vec x), \phi (\vec x), \vec x)$ is a free family".

Answer (score 1):

reductio ad absurdum for both question.

1. What if $\phi(\vec x) = \vec0$ for all $\vec x$ ?
2. What if there is some $\lambda_i$ such $\lambda_2\phi^2(\vec x)+\lambda_1\phi(\vec x)+\lambda_0\vec x = \vec0$

The first one is also relevant to show there is a $\vec x$ such $\phi^2(\vec x) \neq \vec0$.

For the second one, you may want to make $\phi^3(\vec x)$ appear.

> By applying $\phi$ to the equality.

You know something about it but don't use it yet.

One of the criticisms that I have about school system, when you are stuck, just look what they give to you and see what you don't have used, the solution is probably here.

[Solution]

First part:

> If $\phi^2(\vec x) = \vec0$ for all $x$, $A^2 = O_4$ that is a contradiction.
>  So there is a $\vec x$ such $\phi^2(\vec x) \neq \vec0$.
>  Obviously $\phi(\vec x) \neq \vec0$ and $\vec x \neq \vec0$.

Second part:

> If there is $\lambda_i$ such:
>  $\lambda_2\phi^2(\vec x)+\lambda_1\phi(\vec x)+\lambda_0\vec x = \vec0$
>  By applying $\phi$:
>  $\lambda_2\phi^3(\vec x)+\lambda_1\phi^2(\vec x)+\lambda_0\phi(\vec x) = \vec0$
>  But $\phi^3(\vec x) = \vec0$ so:
>  $\lambda_1\phi^2(\vec x)+\lambda_0\phi(\vec x) = \vec0$
>  By applying $\phi$:
>  $\lambda_1\phi^3(\vec x)+\lambda_0\phi^2(\vec x) = \vec0$
>  But $\phi^3(\vec x) = \vec0$ so:
>  $\lambda_0\phi^2(\vec x) = \vec0$
>  That is a contradiction.
>  There is no such $\lambda_i$ and you got a free family.

Comment: Let $\phi$ map the basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ to $e_2,e_3,0,0$ respectively. Then $A^2\neq0$ and $A^3=0.$ The vector $x=e_2$ satisfies $\phi(x)\neq0$ but $(\phi^2(x),\phi(x),x)=(0,e_3,e_2)$ is not free.

Comment: @Justpassingby, $\phi^2 (\vec x) = \vec0$ ? So it's a bad choice for x. Now found a x where $\phi^2 (\vec x) \neq \vec0$ so $\phi (\vec x) \neq \vec0$ so $\vec x \neq \vec0$ and you may show it's a free family.

Comment: So you think that the second assignment should be reformulated as "show that there *exists* an $\vec x$ such that $(\phi^2(\vec x),\phi(\vec x),\vec  x)$ is free"?

Comment: I read the second assignment like this: Show that there exists an $\vec x$ such that $(\phi^2 (\vec x), \phi (\vec x), \vec x)$ is a free family. It's not the same $\vec x$ that the one in the first assignment !

Comment: Makes sense; let's see how the OP responds.